# Autoplay video in the uiwebview

Tags: javascript, xcode, video, uiwebview, autoplay

I have UIWebview contain video in the html ,I need to detect the first video in the html and play it.

Is there any trick in javascript or objective c  to Autoplay the video when page finish loading ?

[image]

Comment: Is this a YouTube video?

Answer (score 0):

If the embedded video is not from Youtube, you must set your UIWebView to allow media playback without user action.

This can be done by setting the `mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction` property of your UIWebView to false.

> **Example**: self.webView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = NO;

---

If you've embedded a YouTube video, you can simply append `&autoplay=1` to the end of the video url.

This will cause the video to autoplay on page load.

Comment: Doesn't work i tried this before i think the solution with javascript

Answer (score 0):

[image]
**Click on inline Playback in storyboard**